# More efficient way to check all conditionals from forEach response using javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, foreach, react-hooks

I have a `<select>` sending the value of the `option` (listed below). The value is then passed into the React Hook. This works but is there a drier/cleaner/more efficient way to go through the conditional statements?

**Select Options**

```
const animals = [
  "Cows", "Pigs", "Sheep", "Goats", "Lambs", "Rabbits"
]
```

**Function**

```
const _updateLocationData = (value) => { 
    var tempLocations = [];
    locations.forEach(function(res) {
        if (value === "Cows" && res.Cows === "Yes") {
            tempLocations.push(res);
        }
        if (value === "Pigs" && res.Pigs === "Yes") {
            tempLocations.push(res);
        }
        if (value === "Sheep" && res.Sheep === "Yes") {
            tempLocations.push(res);
        }
        if (value === "Goats" && res.Goat === "Yes") {
            tempLocations.push(res);
        }
        if (value === "Lambs" && res.Lamb === "Yes") {
            tempLocations.push(res);
        }
        if (value === "Rabbits" && res.Rabbit === "Yes") {
            tempLocations.push(res);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: how about use: if(animals.indexOf(value) > -1 && res[value] === 'Yes') {tempLocations.push(res);}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider something like this: simply confirm `value` is in the desired array and then check that the `[value]` prop of `res` equals `"Yes"`:

```
const animals = [
  "Cows", "Pigs", "Sheep", "Goats", "Lambs", "Rabbits"
]

const _updateLocationData = (value) => { 
    var tempLocations = [];
    locations.forEach(function(res) {
        if (animals.includes(value) && res[value] === "Yes") {
            tempLocations.push(res);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `filter` method to filter out the array.

```js
const animals = [
    "Cows", "Pigs", "Sheep", "Goats", "Lambs", "Rabbits"
];

let locations = [
    { Cows: 'Yes', },
    { Pigs: 'Yes', },
    { Sheep: 'Yes', },
    { Goats: 'Yes', },
    { Lambs: 'Yes', },
    { Rabbits: 'Yes', },
];

const _updateLocationData = (value) => {
    var tempLocations = locations.filter(res => (animals.includes(value) && res[value] === 'Yes'));
    console.log(tempLocations);
}

   _updateLocationData('Cows');

   _updateLocationData('Pigs');
   _updateLocationData('Sheep');
   _updateLocationData('Goats');
```